# Passing values from okhttp-eventsource BackgroundEventHandler to Main Thread

Tags: java, android, okhttp, server-sent-events

I'm trying to use okhttp-eventsource lib to handle Service Sent Events in my Android App but I can't figure out how to pass the values received from the onMessage() method to my Main Thread.
This is my goal: everytime a new JSON is posted to my server I would like to get it and process it on my Main Thread.

This is what my code looks like but it's not working.
`BackgroundEventHandler.onMessage()` method prints on the log the received message, but I get `NetworkOnMainThreadException` on the Main Thread even if `.messages()` method should just return an iterable sequence of SSE messages.

BackgroundEventHandler.java

```
...
public void onMessage(String event, MessageEvent messageEvent){
        Log.d(TAG, messageEvent.getData().toString());
    }
...
```

MainActivity.java

```
...
private void newThingCreated() throws MalformedURLException{
        BackgroundEventSource bes = new BackgroundEventSource.Builder(tcHandler,
                new EventSource.Builder(
                        ConnectStrategy.http(explorer.createQueryUrl("/events/thing_created"))
                                .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        // connectTimeout and other HTTP options are now set through
                        // HttpConnectStrategy
                )
        )
                .threadPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY)
                // threadPriority, and other options related to worker threads,
                // are now properties of BackgroundEventSource
                .build();
        bes.start();
        bes.getEventSource().messages().forEach(new Consumer<MessageEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
                Log.d(TAG, messageEvent.toString());
            }
        });
    }
...
```

`tcHandler` is my BackgroundEventHandler.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using another library: https://github.com/AndroidDeveloper98/ServerSentEventsAndroid which implements a listener. Here's my onMessage() method implementation:

```
 @Override
    public void onMessage(ServerSentEvent sse, String id, String event, String message) {
        Log.d(TAG, "EVENT: " + event);
        lastEventId = id;
        switch(event) {
            case "thing_created":
                consumeExploredThing(Thing.fromJson(message));
                break;
            case "thing_updated":
                Log.d(TAG, message);
                break;
            case "thing_deleted":
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(message);
                    deleteDiscoveredThing(jsonObject.getString("id"));
                } catch (JSONException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            default:
                Log.d(TAG, "ERROR!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).